# Is the dual of a cone can be defined by the dual of the closure of its convex hull?

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-optimization, convex-geometry, convex-hulls

> Let $K$ be a nonempty cone in $\mathbb{R}^n$. We denote the dual of a cone $K$ as $K^*$. Show that $$K^*=(\mathop{\boldsymbol{cl}} \mathop{\boldsymbol{conv}}K)^*$$

How can we describe the closure of the convex hull of a cone mathematically (using algebra)? The proof seems hard to start.

Comment: Isn't a cone already convex and closed?

Comment: not all cones are convex and closed.

Comment: there are cones that are neither convex nor closed, such as $\{(x,y) : (x>0, y=0) \text{ or } (x=0, y>0)\}$.